# Store encrypted database password in Maven

Tags: hibernate, maven

I am looking for a safe way to store my database password. I found out, that I can encrypt my passwords with Maven. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html.

So I created a master password and encrypted my database password with it:

1. `mvn --encrypt-master-password <password>`
2. `vim ~/.m2/settings-security.xml`

   ```
   <settingsSecurity>
       <master>{my-encrypted-master-pw}</master>
   </settingsSecurity>`
   ```
3. `mvn --encrypt-password <db-password>`
4. `vim ~/.m2/settings.xml`

   ```
   <settings>
       <servers>
           <server>
               <id>my.postgres.db</id>
               <username>user</username>
               <password>{my-encrypted-db-password}</password>
           </server>
       </servers>
   </settings>
   ```

Now I am looking for a way to access and decrypt the database password and use it within `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">????</property>
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

There is a Maven extension, which allows you to reference the content of the servers section from any pom.xml: https://github.com/shyiko/servers-maven-extension. But I am struggling to pass it on to hibernate.

Is there a simpler way to store the database password securely?

Comment: Just because something is encrypted does not automatically mean it is also secure.

Comment: I am aware of that. But I want to store my passwords outside of the Maven project, and inject them from the local machine. So, at least you have to break the server and access settings.xml and settings-security.xml. (https://github.com/jelmerk/maven-settings-decoder)

Comment: I am open minded to other approaches to store passwords in a secure way.

Comment: Maven is about buildtime, so the settings.xml from Maven won't help you at runtime. You need to find a solution where you don't depend on Maven configuration.